# Deselecting an item on ListView is causing the IOS App to crash in Xamarin.forms 4.5

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using List View in My app. When I navigate away from the existing page that has a listview, I am setting the selectedItem as null

I am on the Latest Xamarin.IOS . 
Xamarin Forms --- 4.5

I navigate to page 2 and when I come back to my page 1, I am setting the selected Item to null.

How can I deselect the ListView Item without App being crashed?

Exception: Null Reference Exception

Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextActionsCell.get_ScrollDelegate () [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\ContextActionCell.cs:65 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextActionsCell.PrepareForDeselect () [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\ContextActionCell.cs:114 \n  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.OnItemSelected (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs eventArg) [0x00068] in d:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:1157 \n  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`

```
public void on Appearing()
      {
      this.myListView.selectedItem = null ;
      }

private async void ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.SelectedItem != null) {

         await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(e.SelectedItem as AllItems));   

           } else {
                   // display alert
                  }
    }
```

My ListView :

```
<ListView Margin="5,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemSelected="ItemSelected" x:Name="myListView" HasUnevenRows=" true" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
```

Comment: what you posted isn't even valid code.  Please take the time to be sure the code you post is accurate and formatted correctly.  Additionally, if your app is crashing it is extremely helpful if you tell us what exception is causing the crash

Comment: @Jason, I added more explanation and gave reference to the error I am facing.

Comment: I'd suggest testing SelectedItem for null before assigning to it

Comment: what is `ItemSelected` implementation?

Comment: The code you shared is not able to run. Why do you use "==" instead of "="? Can you please share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: @Prateek , I have added my ItemSelected implementation.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT, I just updated my code and the description.

Comment: The code you updated is not able to reproduce the issue. Basically set selectedItem = null won't crash the app.